# Retrieving corresponding cloud mask for Sentinel-2

Tags: python, copernicus, sentinel, sentinelsat

I am processing 2A -level Sentinel2 products (directly from Copernicus using the sentinelsat package in Python). Some of them contain clouds, and I want to mask those clouds. Since the cloud masks in the SCL (Scene Classification Layer) product that come with the 2A products from Copernicus are not great, I want to use masks generated by s2cloudless.

To apply the s2cloudless package, I need the corresponding 1C products because the algorithm only works on the 1C product. When I download the product metadata for my bounding box using sentinelsat's SentinelAPI 'query' function, I get about 6000 results (of which exactly half is 2A and the other half 1C). I do not understand however which 2A product corresponds to which 1C product (so essentially; which 2A product was produced from which 1C product). I need this so I know to which 2a product the cloud mask I produce using the 1C product will belong. The 2A products do have a 'level1cpdiidentifier', though these do not correspond to the 1C product identifiers and there is no description I could find that explains how I can use this identifier. Can anyone explain to me how I can best connect the 2A products to their 1C counterparts?

I've also tried directly downloading the pre-calculated s2cloudless masks from Earth Engine and sentinelhub for the L2A products I already have (I would like to do this without interrupting my current workflow). This did not seem to work without getting a paid subscription.

Comment: Is GEE asking you for a paid subscription? Is the footprint of your AOI too big? I'd use GEE python API for downloading the data. You can use a service account for avoiding authentication in each run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are analyzing S2 L2A products and you want to use a S2 L1C output. I'd do it in two steps: 1) download S2L2A with sentinelsat. 2) Download S2L1C cloud mask from google earth eninge.

First step (downloading s2 L2A, `producttype` is the key for getting only L2A):

```
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt
from datetime import date

api = SentinelAPI('user', 'pass', 'https://apihub.copernicus.eu/apihub')

footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson('some_area.geojson'))

products = api.query(footprint,
                     date=(date(yyyy, mm, dd),date(yyyy, mm, dd)),
                     platformname='Sentinel-2',
                     producttype='S2MSI2A',
                     )

api.download_all(products)
```

Second step (downloading cloud mask from gee):

```
import ee
# ! pip install geetools if you don't have it
from geetools import batch 

ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

sentinel = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY")

# coordinates of the polygon to extract
yourarea = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[x1, y1],
      [x2, y2],
      [x3, y3],
      [x4, y4],
      [x1, y1]]])

# date range
SrtDate = 'yyyy-mm-dd'
EndDate = 'yyyy-mm-dd'

collection = (sentinel
              .filterBounds(yourarea)
              .filterDate(SrtDate,EndDate))

exported_images = batch.Export.imagecollection.toDrive(
    collection=collection,
    folder='S2_Clouds',
    region=yourarea,
    scale=10,
    dataType='int',
    crs= 'EPSG:32XXX', # the CRS of your zone
    maxPixels=10000000000000
)
```

Then you can merge both products

Comment: Thanks again. Do you have any tips on how to best merge the products? I am struggling with that. I was expecting there to be some product ID that would uniquely identify the corresponding mask from EE, but I can't find a unique one.

Comment: Yes, sensing date is a common characteristic between both images. If you list files, you can extract it with something like `[val.split('_')[0] for val in s2clouds_filenames]` and `[val.split('_')[2] for val in s2l2a_filenames]`. Then, depending on the library you are using, you can stack the cloud band to 10, 20 or 60m scene

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Sensing date is indeed common, though not unique. The relationship is N to N. I've also tried sensing date + productdiscriminator, but even then it is not unique. I am trying to add tile_id as well, though no results. Let's for example say I want the cloud mask from EE for ESA's id ='S2A_MSIL2A_20211231T105441_N0301_R051_T31UEV_20211231T135006'.  These both result in nothing: `imageCollection.filterMetadata('PRODUCT_ID', 'equals', id)` or `ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20211231T105441_20211231T135006_T31UEV').getInfo()`. Any tips?

Comment: Use sensing datetime (yyyymmddTHHMMSS date string) + tile. For instance, a S2SR band has this name: `T19JBG_20210309T143731_B02_10m`, the corresponding cloud band has this name: `20210302T144731_20210302T145301_T19JBG`, using both `JBG` and `20210302T144731` you can assign each cloud image to SR scene

Comment: I am so sorry for this, please believe I am trying. This is useful but I just can't manage to do it in EE because I do not know the second date (20210302T145301, in your example) beforehand. ee.Image() - which would probably be the best option - does not accept wildcard or regex it seems. Same with EE's 'stringcontains' function. Filtering on just the first date first (to later filter on JBG) does not work either because it takes incredibly long and just times out (even after filtering to one year and country envelope first). Do you have any tips on how to filter like this?

Comment: Are you doing all work in GEE? I thought you were using python since you're using sentinelset library. I use GEE mostly for downloading images. How is your approach? First downloading S2L2A and then downloading clous images?

Comment: Yes,I use sentinelsat for the main part of the image. I want to use GEE only for the cloud band. So I use sentinelsat to download the metadata for my relevant images. Then I loop over the metadata, and download and process (upsampling, VI-calculations, time serie etc) each image from ESA. This goes well. During the processing, I want to add the cloud image from GEE. I just don't know what function in EE would allow me to search for the corresponding cloud band in GEE with the information I have. For example, in your example I do not know the * part in the following: 20210302T144731_*_T19JBG.

Comment: You can filter by metadata, but first by location (or the process will be slow), like this: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a5c0d4e7db491354bd65c842d78d6766

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, it turned out I was using the wrong CRS and therefore the filter failed and I didn't notice because it times out instead of returns nothing ;). Thank you so much for all your help! I will finish my code, and then post it here later with a reference to you for posterity.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for posting as reference, there are only few examples mixing GEE with other spatial processing

Comment: I start to get why, its more difficult than I expected. I first have to solve new issue; the EE band seem to be about 2 pixels per dimension (so +2 for y and +2 for x) larger than when I cut the ESA image using gdal. This makes masking inaccurate. I am not sure how to fix this yet, I have played with CUTLINE_ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE for gdal but it did not change the results. I suspecteither differences in reprojecting for EE and for GDAL, or one of them does include pixels on the line of the shape whereas the other does not (only inside for example) as culprit. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: Check [this function](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/reproject_match.html)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I will use it if I can't find out why the difference is there in the first place. This since there should not be a difference, and it's better to tackle the issue at the root, I would argue. I guess it must have something to do with the way GDAL cuts using a multipolygon vs EE.

Comment: I am not really finding the solution, so I'm going to post a new thread about this new question. I'll keep you posted though.

Comment: I'm currently preparing the data for doing the same. Although my aim is to create datasets for classification, so I probably my approach won't be the same than yours

Comment: Took a small holiday. I'll keep you posted, but here's the question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/457986/difference-in-clip-results-between-earth-engine-and-python-gdal-using-the-same-g

Answer (score 1):

The names for L1A and L2A products are very similar.
Look for the L1C product which has the same aquisition datetime and tile, it should be sufficient

Here is the naming convention of S2 products: https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/naming-convention

For example, one L2A derived from the L1C:

```
S2B_MSIL1C_20210517T103619_N7990_R008_T30QVE_20210929T075738.SAFE
S2B_MSIL2A_20210517T103619_N7990_R008_T30QVE_20211004T113819.SAFE
```

Only the processing level changes in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers below are very helpful, and helped me understand the process better. I deducted the following viable methods based on aldo_tapia's suggestions. The following works well for me, but if someone has better methods please comment on my code or add an answer:

```
satimg_cloud = imageCollection.filter(
              ee.Filter.stringEndsWith('system:index', tileid)) \
              .filter(ee.Filter.stringStartsWith('system:index', 
                                               datatakestarttime))
```

The 'tileid' and 'datatakestarttime' are metadata you can find in your ESA image; the API returns that information (with those exact names) and are unique to your ESA satellite image. You can get the image in this collection using .first(), and the probabilities by selecting the cloud probability band specifically. Alternatively, you can also filter the collection beforehand on cloud probabilities only (for example using ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY')).

You could also do the following after filtering the image collection per the first code snippet above, though this will include an additional server call with getInfo():

```
ee_img = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY/" + str(satimg_cloud.aggregate_array('system:index').getInfo()[0]))
```